# Why this probability of this problem does not equal to this logical answer?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

### Problem Description:

Sophia has **7** *days* to study **4** *subjects* (x, y, z, p).. Every day she studies one of them.
Obviously, the possible combinations for her schedule are $4^7$, as she can place any subject in any day.

### Question:

How many possible schedule permutations exist where Sophia can study **every subject** at **least once**?

---

My way was the following:

So, I should place at least 4 different subjects in these 7 days. So the probability falls to:
$$P(7, 4)$$
Combining the 3 **remaining days** we have, where we can place any subject we want, the final probability is:
$$P(7, 4) * 4^3$$

But the books tells me (*with a note below the example like it knew I would do it that way*) this is wrong. But why? What is the final result then and why?

Comment: You are over counting.  Say your assigned $4$ are $x-$ Sunday, $y-$ Monday, $z-$ Tuesday, $p-$ Wednesday. and that you "randomly" choose $x$ on Thursday.  That's the same as if the Sunday $x$ were chosen randomly and the Thursday $x$ assigned.

Comment: Hint for the desired count:  it's easier to count those arrangements in which not all four subjects are represented.  Use Inclusion-Exclusion.

Comment: Why am I over counting? I mean isn't the whole meaning to get all the possible probabilities including the one where $x$ is assigned on Thursday and Sunday has a random $x$ and the complete opposite?

Comment: I explained why.  In the example I described, you are counting the arrangement at least twice.  Take the arrangement $\{x,y,z,p,x,x,x\}$.  That one you are counting $4$ times (one each according to which $x$ you choose to say was assigned).

Comment: Let's say you looked at an arbitrary schedule and focused on a random day where subject $x$ was studied. Was that $x$ placed there by the $\binom{7}{4}$ piece or the $4^3$ piece? Since it could be either, this implies that the $\binom{7}{4} \cdot 4^3$ approach will result in a lot of duplicate solutions being counted.

Comment: Alright! You can post an answer if you want! Thank you for the guidance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If the order of the days matters**:

One approach is the inclusion-exclusion principle. We can take the total number of permutations minus those that exclude a subject. Let $A$ represent the event where subject $x$ is excluded, $B$ represent the exclusion of $y$, etc. Then:

\begin{align}
&|A\cup B\cup C\cup D|\\
&=|A|+|B|+|C|+|D|\\
&-(|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|A\cap D|+|B\cap C|+|B\cap D|+|C\cap D|)\\
&+(|A\cap B\cap C|+|A\cap B\cap D|+|A\cap C\cap D|+|B\cap C\cap D|) \\
&-|A\cap B\cap C\cap D|\\
\end{align}

Applying values, we get:

$$4 \cdot (3^7) - 6 \cdot (2^7) + 4 \cdot (1^7) - 0 = 7984$$

Now we take the total number of schedules $4^7$ and subtract the invalid cases to get the final answer:

$$W = 4^7 - 7984 = 8400$$

**If the order of the days does not matter**:

We can immediately cut off $4$ days which will have one subject each.

This reduces the problem to counting subject combinations over $3$ days, which can be treated like a [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)#Theorem_two_2) problem: Imagine that each of the $4$ subjects is a frequency bin and we can allocate $3$ days among them in total. Therefore the total number of ways to study each subject at least once is:

$$W = \binom{3+4-1}{4-1} = 20$$

Those combinations are:

```
ppppxyz
pppxxyz
pppxyyz
pppxyzz
ppxxxyz
ppxxyyz
ppxxyzz
ppxyyyz
ppxyyzz
ppxyzzz
pxxxxyz
pxxxyyz
pxxxyzz
pxxyyyz
pxxyyzz
pxxyzzz
pxyyyyz
pxyyyzz
pxyyzzz
pxyzzzz
```

Comment: I'm not gonna hide it. I can't select the best answer because I'm confused by yours. I can't understand the correlation between my problem with this one.
As Lulu said above, this subject can be solved by Inclusion-Exclusion, but now I'm confused with your answer as well ... 

I just don't want to hide that if I'm gonna select your answer as the best one, I'll have to understand it completely and spend some time more.

Comment: It's counting up the number of ways to have at least one of each subject studied over $7$ days where the order of the days doesn't matter. For example `pxyzzzz` means subject $p$ was studied once, $x$ once, $y$ once, and $z$ four times.

Comment: Oh, so we cut down a lot more combinations in this one right? Because considered that `pxyzzzz` is the same with `zzpxyzz` right?

Comment: Yes, those two would be considered the same (assuming we're just counting combinations as referenced in the original question). If order matters then the number of possible schedules jumps up to $8400$.

Comment: Oh, so it's my fault. :/ Awkward. Actually, days are not considered the same in the problem. So `pxyzzzz` and `zzpxyzz` are not the same. 


The answer comes up to 8400 with Inclusion-Exclusion.
$A_1 \cup A_2 \cup A_3 \cup A_4$ where each A corresponds for a case where one of the 4 subjects is not included.


Hey, sorry it's my fault. Thank you very much though for the analytical answer of yours, How should I edit my answer to look right in a technical matter?

Comment: I'd say "How many possible schedule permutations exist where Sophia can study every subject at least once?" or something similar.

Comment: If you could as well, please edit your answer so I can assign it as the final solution here. Hey, thanks for the help. Even that small matter with the possible combinations, made me understand some things better. So no time was lost by your side for explaining things that don't matter, don't worry :D. They mattered to me.

Comment: @general656 No worries -- answer edited.

Answer (score 2):

To see the problem more immediately, try a simpler example: Sophia has **2** *days* to study **1** *subject* $(x)$. There is only one way to do this: Study $x$ on both days.

But according to your logic, there are two ways, since we can place $1$ subject $x$ in either of $2$ days, then fill in the remaining day with $x$ as well. The problem is that these two descriptions describe the same plan.

Considering simple examples is always a good idea!

Comment: I would upvote you if I could because I loved your example! But I'm sorry that it doesn't include any complete answer :/

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we restrict ourselves to three days and two subjects, $a,b$.

By your method there are three ways to select days to put $a$, then for each two ways to put $b$, then again for each of theses, two ways to select either $a$ or $b$ for the remaining day.   Counting ${}^3\mathrm P_2\cdot 2 ~=~ 3\cdot 2\cdot 2 ~=~ 12$ *distinct* arrangements.

$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}\rm a\_\,\_ \\\rm  \_a\_ \\\rm  \_\,\_a \end{array}\right\}~\to~\left\{\begin{array}{c}\rm ab\_ &\rm a\_b \\\rm ba\_ & \rm \_ab \\ \rm b\_a & \rm \_ba\end{array}\right\}~\to~ \left\{ \begin{array}{c}\rm aba & \rm aab & \rm abb & \rm abb \\ \rm baa & \rm aab & \rm bab & \rm bab \\ \rm baa & \rm aba & \rm bba & \rm bba\end{array}\right\}$$

Wait... those are not all distinct at all.

We have *overcounted* some arrangements.   There are only 6 distinct patterns here.

---

Let us instead count all the ways to arrange two subjects in three days, and then subtract ways to arrange one subject in three days.

$$2^3-2\cdot 1^3 ~=~ 6$$

Extending this back to four subjects and seven days, we need to also apply the **principle of inclusion and exclusion**.

> $$4^7 - \binom 4 1\cdot 3^7 + \binom 42\cdot 2^7-\binom 43\cdot 1^7+ \binom 44\cdot 0^7 ~=~ 840$$